# Run JS function when JQ enqueued

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I would like to run a javascript function when jQuery is ready. This doesn't work:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
?>
<script>
    (function() {
        doJQstuff()
    })();
</script>
```

Any ideas?

```
wp_localize_script( 'search-ajax', 'search_ajax_object',
    array( 
        'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    )
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'search-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/search-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
```

`search-ajax.js`

```
console.log(search_ajax_object) //-> Uncaught ReferenceError: search_ajax_object is not defined
```

Comment: You should load your script via `wp_enqueue_script()` as well, not output it directly in the template. Have you tried that?

Comment: @kero Can you enqueue javascript functions that use php calls inside of the function body?

Comment: No, that is usually bad practice. Either use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to pass data from PHP to JS or query the REST/ajax endpoints from JS.

Comment: @kero I can't get that to work. Can you check the updated question and see what's wrong? :D The object is not accessible from the javascript

Comment: From the doc "Works only if the script has already been added." - so switch the statements (enqueue first, then localize)?

Comment: @kero Ah, yeah that works.

Comment: Happy to help :) Feel free to accept the posted answer. In the end, it solved your original question (why jquery wasn't available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't do that way

first you need to enqueue your script using :

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('ns-likes-dislikes-for-posts-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). 'path/to/your/js/file/from/plugin/directory/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```

in custom js start writing your js with jquery but you can't use `$`, instead use `jQuery`.

if you want to use `$` instead of `jQuery` try this code:

```
(function($){
  // enjoy jquery with $('selector')
})(jQuery)
```

first you need to enqueue script then you can localize it.

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'search-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/search-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
wp_localize_script( 'search-ajax', 'search_ajax_object',
    array( 
        'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    )
);
```